# Bing maps namespace undefined - Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: vb.net, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I'm building a Windows 8.1 Store app using VB.NET & I'm looking to use Bing maps. I have installed the latest Bing Maps for Windows Store extension but unfortunately I'm getting an error when trying to use it.

```
xmlns:bm="using:Bing.Maps"
```

Error I get : "Undefined namespace. The using URI referes to a namespace Bing.Maps that could not be found"

Here is what I have done:

- Reinstalled the Bing SDK
- Changed the Target to x64
- Referenced the Bing Maps & VC++ 2013 for Windows

I have been spending hours on this, tried out every possible solution I came across, restared, rebooted but to no luck. Any help would be really appreciated.

[image: Error I get when I try to include]

Comment: What version of Visual studio 2013, and what version of Bing Maps Sdk?

Comment: VS2013 Update 2 for Windows 8.1 and Bing 1.313.825.0 both of which I presume to be the latest available. I use Bing maps on VS2012 for Windows Phone 8 which works perfectly fine, its just with the Windows 8.1 apps I'm facing issues.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the correct version of the Bing Maps SDK? There are two, one for Windows 8 and another of Windows 8.1:

Win 8: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ebc98390-5320-4088-a2b5-8f276e4530f9

Win8.1: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1